# How to retrieve specific attributes in models in django

Tags: django

We need to retrieve names of all the players of a specific house name in django

models.py:

```
class player(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing a book genre (e.g. Science Fiction, Non Fiction).
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Enter a players name")
    Id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100, help_text="Enter a players Id")
    Num_matches = models.IntegerField()
    Num_baskets = models.IntegerField()
    house_name = models.ForeignKey('House_name',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

views.py:

```
def shivalik(request):
    queryset = player.objects.all().filter(house_name='shivalik' )
    return render(request,'shivalik.html',{'queryset': queryset})
```

shivalik.html:

```
{% extends "basic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h2><li>{{queryset.name}}</li></h2>
{% endblock %}
```

error:

```
ValueError at /bb/shivalik/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'shivalik'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/bb/shivalik/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'shivalik'
```

Answer (score 0):

It because `models.ForeignKey` used for `int`, but not `string` value. you should return `player.objects.all().filter(house_name=<int>)`.

If you need specific name from your `house_name`, you should do this; example in your `models.py`

```
class House_name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ....
```

and then in your queryset;

```
player.objects.filter(house_name__name='shivalik')
```